# Set browser in offline mode using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I am using selenium to test an application, I am starting my browser normally but at some point, I need to switch to offline mode, so far I saw several posts saying that is not possible using selenium unless you start the driver in offline mode ( which is not my case ).

I am using C# and Selenium, and I have planned to integrate my project to run it remotely.

Do you know if there is a way to switch the browser to offline mode using Javascript? or any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could integrate a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) into your application and coordinate with it to either pass through requests as usual, or, if you flag it to do so, drop all requests and simulate failures.

Service Workers essentially act as a proxy for all requests and you can choose how to handle them (e.g. cache them, refresh data from the server, or simply deny the requests).